# PHP Excel ERROR : Uncaught PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am uploading a excel file and writing 4 values in four cells of that excel file and want to get result from other cells (Formulas already written there in Excel). I have tested this by creating a sample application and it was working correct. But Now I am trying this with complex excel file with many formulas and sheets in it and It is returning this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception: COMP FINAL!A3 -> Formula Error: Unexpected , in /opt/lampp/htdocs/excel_test/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Cell.php:291 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/excel_test/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5/Worksheet.php(436): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue() #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/excel_test/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php(175): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5_Worksheet->close() #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/excel_test/application/controllers/Admin.php(69): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/excel_test/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(360): Admin->index() #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/excel_test/index.php(202): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #5 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/excel_test/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 291

I also checked here : [Fatal error: Uncaught PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784571/fatal-error-uncaught-phpexcel-calculation-exception), But it didn't help me, so can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about you show us the code that is failing?

Comment: Code is working correctly with sample file, but I think some changes in config of PHPExcel is needed to solve this issue so, I did not write code here.

Comment: So what is the formula in cell `COMP FINAL!A3`?